# How to sending gmail using javamail in android

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am getting the following issue when I am sending email.

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. z9sm9651423pdp.73 - gsmtp

I tried to send mail using following code

```
public class SendMyMail {
private String from;
private String to;
private String subject;
private String text;

public SendMyMail(String from, String to, String subject, String text) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.text = text;
}

// send method is called in the end
public boolean send() throws MessagingException {

    boolean sent = false;
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "gsmtps");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");// set to false for no username
    props.put("mail.debug", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

    InternetAddress fromAddress = null;
    InternetAddress toAddress = null;
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect();
    try {
        Message simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
        fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
        toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
        simpleMessage.setFrom(fromAddress);
        simpleMessage.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
        simpleMessage.setSubject(subject);
        simpleMessage.setText(text);
        transport.sendMessage(simpleMessage,
                simpleMessage.getAllRecipients());
        sent = true;
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        transport.close();
    }
    return sent;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The [JavaMail FAQ has a simple example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

If you prefer to keep using your code, fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), then try setting the property "mail.smtp.starttls.enable" to "true".

Note that there is no "gsmtps" protocol, so you can remove that setting.

And of course you **are** going to need to supply a username and password when you connect.